# PHPUnit + Selenium `InvalidArgumentException: Element not found`

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Following example from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/), trying to implement some Selenium testing.

**Test class code:**

```
class StackoverflowTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowserUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/');
        $this->setBrowser('chrome');

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function onNotSuccessfulTest(Throwable $e): void
    {
        $filedata = $this->currentScreenshot();
        $file     = __DIR__ . '/' . time() . '.png';
        file_put_contents($file, $filedata);

        parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function visit_home_page_case_success()
    {
        $this->url('/');
        dump($this->title());
        dd($this->byTag('body')->text()); //line 35
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

...

`"Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers"`

...

`There was 1 error:
1) ...\StackoverflowTest::visit_home_page_case_success
InvalidArgumentException: Element not found.`

...

`.../StackoverflowTest.php:35`

...

**Screenshot:**

[image]

What's wrong and how can I to interact with the page elements?

Repeated [here](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/439#issuecomment-561740660):

> Unfortunately phpunit-selenium does not support W3C mode yet, you can force it to use the non-w3c mode by:

```
$this->setDesiredCapabilities(['chromeOptions' => ['w3c' => false]]);
```